# Proof verification: The derived set of a subset A in a metric space is closed.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Currently I'm reading "Introduction to Topology" by Theodore. I want to show that the derived set $A'$ of a subset A in a metric space is closed. Can anyone help me check my proof?

It suffices to show that $\overline{A'}\subseteq A'$.
Let $a\in \overline{A'}$ and let $r>0$.
Since a is adherent to $A'$, there exists some point $y \in B(a;r/2) \cap A'$. If $y=a$, then we are finised.
If $y\neq a$, set $h=\min\{r/2,d(a,y)\}$. Since y is a limit point of a, for $h>0$, there exists some point $z\in B(y;h)-\{y\} \cap A$.
And $$d(a,z) \leq d(a,y) + d(y,z) < \frac{r}{2} + \frac{r}{2} = r$$
Additionally we see that $z\neq a$ because of our choice of $h$. Thus $z\in B(a;r)-\{a\} \cap A$ and $a\in A'$.

Comment: It is correct but I would specify the reason why $z\neq a$. If $z=a$, then we would have that $h\leq d(a,y)=d(z,y)<h$, a contradiction.